# HTTP request spent too much time on "Request Sent"(by chrome devtools)

Tags: web-applications, plotly-dash

I have a Python Dash app, which is deployed on apache server. The problem is that the UIs (e.g. dropdowns) feel a lot more responsive when run locally than deployed on server. On close inspection on network tab in chrome devtools, it showed that the lagging is due to much time spent on following processes: "Request sent", "stalled", etc.

[chrome devtools network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkzDO.png)

My question is, what is actually leading to this phenomenon and how shall I go about solving this issue? (would be ok if it's solution to web app in general, in context of Dash, most appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue.

Sometimes there might be some hidden components that keeps on running. In my case, I created a intermediate div to contain a large data frame. After I removed intermediate-df in my callbacks, it was much faster, from 50s to 5 secs.

Comment: I found instead by adopting "clientside callback" [link](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) (basically re-writing the callback in JS). The performance can be improved. Essentially for pure frontend task (even I stored relevant data in localstorage), the callback needs to communicate with its server. This is largely prone to network latency if you have a large number of callbacks communicating with server.

Comment: @Bohan Would you guys mind sharing the snippet of what you did? I am facing similar issues!!!

Comment: Hey bro, the most direct solution to this problem is, learn JavaScript, learn Reactjs or Vuejs. Over time, you will find how  beautiful a programming language JS is and how ingenieous these frameworks are. Good luck!